# Перенос пользователей Windows Server 2003 R2 с AD на Windows Server 2003 R2 без AD

Tags: active-directory, сервер

Собственно сабж: сервак Supermicro, который используется как сервер терминалов, меняем на более новый HP.Зачем нужно было AD - не знаю, т.к. делалось задолго до меня, но сейчас поставили задание AD убрать, а настройки юзверей оставить, чтобы они не почувствовали на себе болезненного перехода на новое железо.Сейчас пользователей 115, большинство из которых работает удаленно.Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем можно сделать перенос на новый сервак?

P.S.: admt & usmt пробовал, но 1 работает только с AD, а второй - только с локальными учетками.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы. Решил данную задачу вручную созданием новых учетных записей.

Comment: неужели "вручную" перебивали и переносили профили? О_о

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Комманда **dsmode user** ничем не поможет.

Автор вопроса понимает что при удалении AD, если будет предпринята попытка создания пользователей, то у вновь созданных пользователей все равно будет другой UID, т.к. изначально UID включает в себя SID домена.

Соответвенно будут недоступны уже настроенные профили в терминальном сервере.

AD ставят чтобы упростить работу с большим кол-вом пользователей и компьютеров в сети предприятия (да и еще куча других примочек с настройками, в том числе и работа в терминале). Точно ли надо ее сносить?

Есть такая утилита [User Profile Wizard](http://www.forensit.com/ru/comparison.html), прочитайте про нее, вроде она может спасти ваши уже созданые профили в терминальном сервере.

Comment: Спасибо за понимание. На самом деле раньше в сети было много пользователей и AD поставили для упрощения администрирования и прочих "плюшек". Сейчас количество пользователей уменьшилось и все, кроме нашего отдела и еще 2-х человек, подключаются удаленно через VPN. Поэтому прошу прощения за неточность первого сообщения: сейчас в сети 57 человек. С данной задачей справился вручную, и на данный момент перенос практически завершен. Осталось несколько пользователей, которые еще не опробовали новый сервер.

Comment: Поэтому не могу быть уверен в том, что все настройки и нужные файлы расположены на "привычных" местах.

Comment: Прошу тогда поделится опытом (если конечно не лениво) и описать все шаги что и как переносили, какое ПО где и когда задействовали, что с паролями, UID пользователей и их профилями на локальных компьютерах и в терминалах. Поподробней. Если не тут (хотя думаю другим тоже будет полезно), то мне на мыло s_live сабака list.ru

Comment: Сразу прошу прощения за столь долгое отсутствие. По просьбе Home рассказываю как справился с заданием.Поскольку времени на решение данного вопроса было недостаточно, а поиски в интернете ни к чему не привели, то было принято решение осуществить перенос вручную.Информация, которую мне нужно было знать:• имена учетных записей;• пароли к учетным записям;• настройки учетных записей;• нужные базы данных, файлы пользователей и прочая мелочь.

Comment: 1. Имена учетных записей взял со старого сервера. Тут, думаю, ничего объяснять не нужно.2. Пароли к учеткам. Так как информационной безопасности на многих фирмах уделяется мало (а точнее сказать "совсем не уделяется") внимания, то и наша фирма не стала исключением. Некоторые пароли я помнил, поскольку неоднократно бывал в других офисах и настраивал VPN'ы, Remote Desktop'ы, etc; некоторые пользователи помнили свои пароли; а те, кто не помнил свой пароль доставали бумажечки с записанными или (как у Задорнова: "а сейчас приготовились... точно готовы? Вдохнули!") спрашивали у соседей по кабинету

Comment: 3. Настройки учетных записей тоже посмотрел на старом сервере. ничего существенного не обнаружил.4. Файлы. Тут надо отметить, что нужно было сбросить параметры безопасности и доступа для папок, но на ошибках учатся. Файлы и папки были восстановлены идентично структуре на старом сервере (чуть ниже объясню почему). Базы данных 1С перенес без каких-либо проблем. Программы некоторые были установлены по-новой, некоторые (типа "клиент-банки" и т.п.) перенесены банальным копи-пастингом.Вот так все происходило.

Comment: Небольшие дополнения. Хронология событий:• 11.12: получено задание, был задан вопрос.• 12.12: создание учетных записей на новом сервере, поездка на другой офис с целью собрать пароли и узнать про жизненно важные файлы на сервере. После окончания рабочего дня был подключен новые сервер.

Comment: • 13.12(утро): звонки от пользователей, связанные с невозможностью записать в "свою" папку данные. Вот и вылезла проблема с безопасностью. Безопасность сбросил и назначил новые права доступа. Звонки по непривычному расположению значков на рабочем столе, и, вообще, "невозможностью ничего найти" © отдел кадров. Решалось банальным изменением вида "Плитка" ↔ "Таблица" ↔ "Список". • 13.12(вечер): кроме, указанных выше, проблем не возникало. Перенос сервера, считаю, завершен успешно.Спасибо за интерес, проявленный к поднятой теме.

Comment: Я так понимаю что все пользователи которые работали в терминале при заходе на сервер (уже без АД) получили новые профили? Или Вы еще шаманили в реестре?HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\ProfileList

Comment: Нет, никаких действий в реестре не производил. Каждый пользователь получил новый профиль практически идентичный старому. Я не претендую на профессионализм данного решения, но задача была решена, а это для меня, на данный момент, главное. Если наткнусь на более рациональное решение, то обязательно поделюсь.P.S.: Теперь у меня есть несколько машин, из которых я могу смоделировать  небольшую сеть, и сервер. Сейчас изучаю соответствующую литературу и пытаюсь повысить уровень своих знаний и умений.

Comment: теперь ясно

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте Ideal Migration